# SQL Query Issue iOS

Tags: ios, swift, sqlite, grdb

I'm working on an app that uses SQLite database, I mostly use [inloop](https://inloop.github.io/sqlite-viewer/#) and [DB Browser for SQLite](https://sqlitebrowser.org/) on my Mac. In the iOS app (Develop with Swift), I'm using the GRDB library for SQLite.

The problem is some of the queries are working in the `DB Browser for SQLite` but not working on `inloop` (No any error also same time not showing any result) for example below query,

```
select
  sum(e.amount) as Total,
  strftime("%Y%m%d", entrydate / 1000, 'unixepoch') as day,
  count(c.cid) as trxcount,
  group_concat(
    DISTINCT(
      c.first_name || ' ' || ifnull(c.middle_name, '') || ' ' || ifnull(c.last_name, '')
    )
  ) as parties
from
  LedgerEntry e
  inner join Customer c on e.customer_id = c.cid
where
  e.entrydate >= 1655271792800
  and e.entrydate <= 1655271792868
  and e.type = 0
group by
  day
order by
  day asc
```

The question is not about the `inloop` problem but whatever queries are not working in the `inloop` are also not working with GRDB in my app. Can someone please explain what's the main reason for this? The app is developed with `Swift 5`

Database connection code.

```
import Foundation
import GRDB


class SBC_DailyBalanceByType : Codable, FetchableRecord, PersistableRecord {
    var total : Double?
    var day : Int?
    var trxcount : Int?
    var parties : String?
}


class SB_DailyBalanceByType : NSObject {
    
    
    static let shared = SB_DailyBalanceByType()
    static var arrData = [SBC_DailyBalanceByType]()
    
    
    func GetBal(type: Int, startDate:Int, endDate:Int, completion: @escaping ([SBC_DailyBalanceByType]?) -> ()) {
        
        do {
            ///GRDB
            let dbQueue = try DatabaseQueue(path: SBGlobal.filePath)
            
            //1655271792800
            //1655271792868
            
            let query = "select sum(e.amount) as Total,strftime(\"%Y%m%d\", entrydate / 1000, 'unixepoch') as day,count(c.cid) as trxcount,group_concat(DISTINCT(c.first_name || ' ' || ifnull(c.middle_name, '') || ' ' || ifnull(c.last_name, ''))) as parties from LedgerEntry e inner join Customer c on e.customer_id = c.cid where e.entrydate >= \(1655271792800) and e.entrydate <= \(1655271792868) and e.type = \(0) group by day order by day asc"


            let players: [SBC_DailyBalanceByType] = try dbQueue.read { db in
                try SBC_DailyBalanceByType.fetchAll(db, sql: query)
            }
            
            SB_DailyBalanceByType.arrData.append(contentsOf: players)
            
            print(players)

        } catch {
            print (error)
        }
        completion(SB_DailyBalanceByType.arrData)
    }
    
}
```

However, I made some changes in the query for an alternative solution that works with GRDB. So I assume that some problem with `strftime` function.

```
SELECT
  SUM(e.amount) AS Total,
  SUBSTR(DATE('1970-01-01', '+' || (e.entrydate / 1000) || ' SECONDS'), 1, 10) AS day,
  COUNT(c.cid) AS trxcount,
  GROUP_CONCAT(
    COALESCE(c.first_name, '') || ' ' || COALESCE(c.middle_name, '') || ' ' || COALESCE(c.last_name, '')
  ) AS parties
FROM
  LedgerEntry e
  INNER JOIN Customer c ON e.customer_id = c.cid
WHERE
  e.entrydate BETWEEN 1655271792800
  AND 1655271792868
  AND e.type = 0
GROUP BY
  day
ORDER BY
  day ASC;
```

Comment: Hi Krunal, it might be helpful for us to know the specific error messages that you get. Similarly, how do you connect to the database in Swift? Is it maybe a connection issue and not an issue with the query? Please provide more details.

Comment: Not getting any errors just get zero results. Still, let me attach the code for your reference.

Comment: If there is no error, then it shouldn't be a technical issue. It's probably related to your specific contents of your database that you're hitting with this specific query. I would suggest to fire basic queries and see what comes out and whether that matches your DB contents. Then make the query a bit more complex, check again. As it seems it's related to your data, we can't say what the issue is.

Comment: I agree with @JanMensch, it's maybe related to the actual database content. To get a quick dump of the database content, use `dbWriter.dumpContent()` (GRDB 6.20+). This helps checking your assumptions. Also, beware that the DB Browser for SQLite might not use the exact same SQLite version as your app.